# What's a more elegant rephrasing of this cropping algorithm? (in Python)

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, python, crop

I want to crop a thumbnail image in my Django application, so that I get a quadratic image that shows the center of the image. This is not very hard, I agree.

I have already written some code that does exactly this, but somehow it lacks a certain ... elegance. I don't want to play code golf, but there must be a way to express this shorter and more pythonic, I think.

```
x = y = 200 # intended size
image = Image.open(filename)
width = image.size[0]
height = image.size[1]
if (width > height):
    crop_box = ( ((width - height)/2), 0, ((width - height)/2)+height, height )
    image = image.crop(crop_box)
elif (height > width):
    crop_box = ( 0, ((height - width)/2), width, ((height - width)/2)+width )
    image = image.crop(crop_box)
image.thumbnail([x, y], Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Do you have any ideas, SO?

**edit:** explained x, y

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should do.

```
size = min(image.Size)

originX = image.Size[0] / 2 - size / 2
originY = image.Size[1] / 2 - size / 2

cropBox = (originX, originY, originX + size, originY + size)
```

Comment: I like having width and height variables explicitly named.  Otherwise someone reading this code has to find the documentation for Image.Size

Comment: May be there are image.Width and image.Height properties, but I don't know. I just inferred the code from the qustion.

Answer (score 6):

The `fit()` function in the PIL [ImageOps](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageops.htm) module does what you want:

```
ImageOps.fit(image, (min(*image.size),) * 2, Image.ANTIALIAS, 0, (.5, .5))
```

Comment: Hmm.. this doesn't really seem to produce square images. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The fit() function returns a new image object, I forgot to mention that. Maybe it's that?

Answer (score 1):

```
width, height = image.size
if width > height:
    crop_box = # something 1
else:
    crop_box = # something 2
image = image.crop(crop_box)
image.thumbnail([x, x], Image.ANTIALIAS)   # explicitly show "square" thumbnail
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to a content analysis of a jepg image. I wish to take a jpeg imafe say 251 x 261 and pass it through an algorithm to crop it to say 96 x 87. Can this program do that like t write an intelligent cropping algorithm, with a prompt to rezie the image.